# copy a listview item to to another listview by index number

Tags: c#, listview, copy

How can I copy an item from `listview1` to `listview2` by using item's `index`?

Comment: What have you done so far? Share your code.

Comment: Could you reformulate that? Could you reformulate that?

Comment: sorry but because of the site rules that my message is so short then I solved like this twice. I thought that mod will refix it.

Comment: @zorbeyaslan: The question quality filter was suggesting that you add more meaningful information.  Asking a bad question *twice* doesn't make it a good question.

Comment: What do you mean by copy? Do you want to add the selected item from listview1 to listview2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample to play around with. Hope it is self-explanatory.

```
// First ListView
ListViewFirst.Items.Add("Apple");
ListViewFirst.Items.Add("Orange");
ListViewFirst.Items.Add("Banana");
ListViewFirst.Items.Add("Melon");
ListViewFirst.Items.Add("WaterMelon");

// Copy to second list view using items index 
var index = 4;
var item = ListViewFirst.Items[index].Clone() as ListViewItem;
ListViewSecond.Items.Add(item);
```

This will **clone** the `ListViewItem` at index `4` (which is, WaterMelon) and we insert the cloned instance to second ListView.

Note that you have to either `clone` the item or `remove` and `add` the item.

Comment: thanks. just you understood me and my emmergency. thanks. your code is working.

Comment: Happy that it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for copying. This will access the item 0 from listview1 and add to listview2

```
listview2.Items.Add(listview1.Items[0]);
```